# Are "pay phones" still, if ever, called "pay stations" in the U.S.?

Tags: american-english, word-usage, ambiguity, dialects

What is ***pay station*** in the U.S.?

If you look it up, say, on ODO, it is defined as an AmEng equivalent of **pay phone**.

> pay station: *n.* US term for pay phone [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pay-station)

Now, if you search Google Images for pictures of respectively a pay phone and a pay station, this is what you get:

> [pay phone](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22payphone%22&biw=413&bih=271&prmd=vimn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpxZWSwKLKAhVCDQ4KHYcfBDcQ_AUIBygC)
>
> [pay station](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22payphone%22&biw=413&bih=271&prmd=vimn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpxZWSwKLKAhVCDQ4KHYcfBDcQ_AUIBygC#tbm=isch&q=%22pay+station%22)

And so, my question is:

"If" *pay station* is an older term for *pay phone* in the U.S., when did the meaning shift from *pay phone* to what I'd broadly call, "automated parking meter" actually occur, and, most of all, why is that newer or alternate sense of *pay station* apparently not supported by any authoritative dictionaries [available online](https://www.google.fr/search?biw=608&bih=400&noj=1&ei=TgqUVpezFcXXOtD5gcAM&q=%22pay+station%22+definition&oq=%22pay+station%22+definition&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3..0i19j0i22i30i19l2j0i8i13i30i19l2.425895.442118.0.443402.50.39.0.0.0.0.736.9973.0j6j16j8j2j1j1.34.0....0...1c.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..25.25.6555.e6fZuNXu8ls)?

Comment: I’ve never heard them called pay stations in the U. S. - ever.  Sometimes I wonder where these dictionaries get their info.

Comment: I've certainly heard them called "pay stations" in the US.  (And I've almost always seen "pay phone", not "payphone".)  Of course one rarely hears/reads either term anymore.

Comment: What is this 'payphone' of which you speak? Google images leads me to believe it is a phone made for giants with no screen and planted in the ground.

Comment: @Jim - Apparently, [old people](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/70861/hot-licks).

Comment: Elian, I think you're getting lots of info here. 1) no one uses 'pay station' nowadays (I think never) 2) ODO has outdated definitions, so good to mistrust.

Comment: @Mitch Sure, but then why's that none of the dictionaries available online seem to support that new meaning of "pay station" i.e. "automated parking meter"?

Comment: The only sense I (mid-west region U.S.) have ever heard *pay station* is at certain parking garages, you need to pay and get your ticket validated at an automated kiosk in the lobby, before you return to your car.  These garages have no "toll booth" at the exits- you have to insert your validated ticket.  This is what is shown in some of your images.

Comment: I'm old-ish and from the US and never heard pay phones referred to as pay stations.  Parking lot pay stations are in use currently if that's any help.

Comment: @Jim: I'd never seen the usage before (perhaps unsurprisingly, since I'm a Brit). But Google Books claims 107 written instances of [calling from a pay station](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22calling+from+a+pay+station%22) - which I *did* find surprisingly high when compared to [Calling from a payphone](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22calling+from+a+payphone%22). It turns out that's because 3370 writers used [Calling from a pay phone](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22calling+from+a+pay+phone%22) (one word bad, two words good? :)

Comment: @KristinaLopez It does. But why has the new meaning of "pay station" not  yet made its way into the dictionaries? Are parking lot pay stations such a new device in the U.S.? ;)

Comment: I'm not sure @Elian.  I guess "pay station"  may not have the cachet of other new OED words such as "staycation" and "selfie"! lol!

Comment: Elian, dictionaries aren't perfect. It' not like some magical connection to the transcendental oversoul of linguistic competency. A bunch of people have to edit things and have committee meetings over every item (except for Urban Dictionary and wiktionary, anything goes there). Also Dictionaries tend to be conservative: once in, it doesn't come out. You should write ODO and tell the to put 'obsolete' on the payphone entry and just have an entry that means 'automatic pay machine' or similar.

Comment: @Mazura - I resemble that remark!!

Comment: @Elian -- In this part of the country parking lot "pay stations" have only been around for 5 years or so.  While dictionaries attempt to pick up *new* words (especially popular ones) within 5 years or so, it likely takes 10-20 years for old definitions to be overhauled.

Comment: @HotLicks By *parking lot pay station* do you mean [one of these](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=car+park+payment+machine&num=50&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwit-43GhKPKAhXI1BoKHbfMA1cQsAQIJg&biw=1366&bih=622)? If so, it confirms my oft-expressed view that you are more inclined to name things than we are. In Britain the system is simply known as *pay on foot*. But they are increasingly being replaced by cashless parking by mobile phone to a number which knows who you are, your car reg no, and your bank card number.

Comment: @WS2 - Yeah, something like that.  The first unit in our small city went in 2-3 years ago.  I suppose they've had them longer in Minneapolis (where they also have pay stations for on-street parking meters), but not much longer than 5 years.  Maybe in Los Angeles they've had them longer.  Haven't seen the phone-operated scheme yet, but I'm sure it's just a matter of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that [pay station](https://books.google.it/books?id=5uTmAAAAMAAJ&q=%22pay%20station%22&dq=%22pay%20station%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_j5TmzqLKAhVCqA4KHcAQD9wQ6AEIMDAC) was used to refer to telephony in the early 20th century. From "Telephony, volume 11" (1906):

> - NEW TELEPHONE RECORDING PAY STATION. The subject of pay stations is one of great interest and concern, as it is one of the most important devices in the equipment of telephone systems.

From: [Webster's New World Telecom Dictionary - Pagina 365](https://books.google.it/books?id=EXHVTLms96oC&pg=PA365&dq=%22pay%20station%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZ293y4aLKAhVGoA4KHXVOAhcQ6AEINTAC#v=onepage&q=%22pay%20station%22&f=false)

> - A pay telephone is no longer a common sight in North America and many developed regions of the world as the low cost and wide availability of cellular phones have made pay phones unprofitable. ***Synonymous with payphone is pay station.***

AmE [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pay%20station%2Cpay%20phones&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpay%20station%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpay%20phones%3B%2Cc0) shows that the popularity of "payphone"  over "pay station" started and increased from  the late 60's.

[Payphone](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=payphone%20) (n.):

> - also pay-phone, 1906, from pay (v.) + phone (n.). (Etymonline)

Comment: [This](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pay+station%2Cpay+phone+%2B+payphone+%2B+pay-phone&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpay%20station%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28pay%20phone%20%2B%20payphone%20%2B%20pay%20-%20phone%29%3B%2Cc0) suggests 'phone' was always more popular. 'Station' seems to have been a term used largely by the phone companies.

Comment: If you Ngram "pay phone" rather than "pay phones" the difference is even more dramatic.

Comment: I suspect that StoneyB's suggestion is correct -- the phone companies used (and may still use) "pay station", while most customers used (but no longer use) "pay phone".

Comment: @HotLicks - pay station is probably a more 'technical' term. The Webster Telecom Dictionary just says they are synonyms.

Comment: @Josh61 - Yeah, there were at one time sometimes "pay phones without the slots" seen in train stations and the like.  These were to be used to make collect calls.  (No such thing as credit card calls at the time, though I think it may have been possible to "charge to another number".)  They were probably referred to as "public stations" or some such, and "pay station" would have been used to differentiate the "station" that had coin slots.

Comment: As a 66-year-old native Californian with a friend who was in the telecommunications industry for more than 40 years before her retirement, this is the *first and only time* I have ever heard of a "pay station" with regards to telephony. Pay phone? Of course. Pay station? Never.

Comment: @HotLicks Looks like "comfort station," a genteelism for "restroom," is even more common than "pay station." https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comfort+station%2Cpay+station%2Ccomfort+stations%2Cpay+stations&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomfort%20station%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpay%20station%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomfort%20stations%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpay%20stations%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @MarkHubbard How about "pay station" in the sense "automated parking pay machine"? Have you ever heard or read it used that way?

Comment: @Elian, I was just in a pay parking deck last week, and I believe "Pay Station" was what had been written in a temporary sign/placard indicating that the attendant was away from that booth and the only way to pay was by using the automated machine, which took both cash and credit/debit card. I've also never heard the expression used in reference to phones. Never.